# How to parse and transform all source code files from an sbt project with scalameta?

Tags: scala, sbt, scalameta

I would like to use scalameta to parse ALL source code files from an SBT based Scala project and transform them.
As the documentation states (https://scalameta.org/docs/trees/guide.html#from-programs-with-multiple-top-level-statements) I can parse SBT files with scalameta but how do I get the corresponding source code files of the project?
Do I have to filter for all .scala files in the src/main/scala folder manually?

Answer (score 0):

As [written](https://scalameta.org/docs/semanticdb/guide.html#consuming-semanticdb) in documentation about SemanticDB they added a function to work with all `.semanticdb` files to `internal` package. I guess you can do similar thing with `.scala` or `.sbt` files. Well, basically, yes, it's on your own.

https://github.com/scalameta/scalameta/issues/1566

https://github.com/scalameta/scalameta/blob/master/semanticdb/semanticdb/src/main/scala/scala/meta/internal/semanticdb/Locator.scala

---

Here is example how to handle all source files in a directory with sbt + Scalameta https://github.com/DmytroMitin/scalameta-demo